# How to show element in some route with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I need a way to use `ng-show` on some elements in `views` or `directives`.

In my application I'm using something like this:

```
if ($location.$path() == '/edit') {
 $scope.showBorder = true
}
```

But this way dose not work properly in `directives`, since inside of those it only works once.

Comment: Why not to use `$scope.showBorder = $location.$path() === '/edit';`?

Comment: @VisioN i used this but if this app injects in other app maybe this way dose not work .